# How do I post data to php script and get result in with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I am making a chrome extension. How do I post data to my PHP script and get the response with my chrome extension? I know about ajax etc but can someone give me an example as apparently I have to do stuff with the manifest as well to allow my external PHP script. And I can't find any examples on how to do this with a chrome extension.

Comment: Use any standard example and additionally [specify the URL in permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr).

Comment: Thank you I will look into this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any standard example and additionally specify the URL in permissions.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr